# Can't store my timer values in a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I asked yesterday about saving a timer value when the browser closes and then start counting again when the user opens it. I've found that using cookies must be a good solution, so i've added the set and getcookie functions, but still i can't get my timer values. This might be easy, but i cant see what's wrong because i'm still too noob in javascript. Does someone know what i'm doing wrong? thank you!! here's the code i have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var sec = 0;
var min =  0;
var hr = 0;
var dias = 0;
var bool = true;
function stopwatch() {
        sec++;
        if (sec == 60) {
            sec = 0;
            min += 1;
        }

        if (min == 60) {
            min = 0;
            hr += 1;
        }

        if (hr == 24) {
            hr = 0;
            dias += 1;
        }

        totalTime = ((dias<=9) ? "0" + dias : dias) + "d, " + ((hr<=9) ? "0" + hr : hr) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + ((sec<=9) ? "0" + sec : sec);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = totalTime;
        if (bool == true) {
        start = setTimeout("stopwatch()", 1000);
        }

    }

function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
}



function getCookie (name) {
    var cname = name + "=";               
    var dc = document.cookie;

    if (dc.length > 0) {              
        begin = dc.indexOf(cname);       
            if (begin != -1) {           
            begin += cname.length;       
            end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
                if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
                return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
            } 
        }
    return null;
}


var exp = new Date();                                  
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="stopwatch()">
    <div id="timer" name="timer"> </div>
  <button onclick="bool = false"; > pause </button>
  <button onclick="bool = true;stopwatch();" > resume </button>

    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Set a Cookie" onClick="setCookie('myCookie',timer.value, exp)">
    </form>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Get Cookie Value" onClick="this.form.tf.value = getCookie('myCookie')">
<input type="text" name="tf" size="30">
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as [@floorish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10962276/1015609) said, `timer.value` is not exist because `timer` is a DIV element and did not have `value` property.

So, you need to change `timer.value` to `document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML` and would be fine.

[Live jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zztbg/)

---

**EDIT 1:**

If you want the timer start counting where it saved on the cookie, you should read the cookie when the page is loaded. I made it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="timer">&nbsp;</div>
<button id="switcher"></button>
<p><input type="button" id="setCookie" value="Set a Cookie"></p>
<p><input type="button" id="getCookie" value="Get Cookie Value"> <input type="text" id="lastTime" size="30"></p>
<script>
/**
 * Set cookie 
 * @param {string} name Name of cookie
 * @param {string} value Value of the cookie
 * @param {object} expires Date object of expire time
 */
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
}

/**
 * Get cookie 
 * @param {string} name Name of cookie
 * @return {?string}
 */
function getCookie(name) {
    var cname = name + "=";               
    var dc = document.cookie;

    if (dc.length > 0) {              
    begin = dc.indexOf(cname);       
      if (begin != -1) {           
      begin += cname.length;       
      end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
        return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
      } 
    }
    return null;
}

var time;

/**
 * Format time and return formatted string
 * @param {number} time Time in seconds that will formatted
 * @return {string}
 */
function formatTime(time) {
  var days = parseInt(time / 86400, 10); // Calculate days from seconds and delete decimals.
  if (0 > days) {
    days = 0;
  }

  var hours = parseInt((time -  days * 86400) / 3600, 10); // Calculate hours from seconds and delete decimals.
  if (0 > hours) {
    hours = 0;
  }

  var mins = parseInt((time -  days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60, 10); // Calculate minutes from seconds and delete decimals.
  if (0 > mins) {
    mins = 0;
  }

  var seconds = parseInt(time - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - mins * 60, 10); // Calculate remain seconds.

  // Array for the time display, the content is something like:
  //   array(3) {
  //     0: '01',
  //     1: '57',
  //     2: '31'
  //   }
  var displayHours = [
    ((hours <= 9) ? '0' + hours : hours),
    ((mins <= 9) ? '0' + mins : mins),
    ((seconds <= 9) ? '0' + seconds : seconds)
  ];

  // Return formatted days and the displayHours is joined with ' : ', then it like this:
  //   '00d, ' + '01 : 57 : 31'
  return ((days <= 9) ? '0' + days : days) + 'd, ' + displayHours.join(' : ');
}

/**
 * Append to the 'timer' DIV the formatted time
 */
function watch() {
  // Append to the 'timer' DIV a formatted time
  //   ++time equal time = time + 1
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = formatTime(++time);
}

/**
 * @type {?object} Variable to handle the interval timer.
 */
var timer = null;

/**
 * Switch between 'pause' and 'resume' time
 */
var switcher = function () {
  if (timer) { // If timer is assigned and not null
    clearInterval(timer); // Clear the interval to stop
    timer = null; // Null the timer
    document.getElementById('switcher').innerHTML = 'Resume'; // Change the word of the button to 'Resume'.
  } else {
    timer = setInterval(watch, 1000); // Start the interval timer
    document.getElementById('switcher').innerHTML = 'Pause'; // Change the word of the button to 'Pause'.
  }
};

// Assign on click event to 'switcher' button
document.getElementById('switcher').onclick = switcher;

// Assign on click event to 'setCookie' button
document.getElementById('setCookie').onclick = function () {
  // New Date object for the expire time
  var exp = new Date();
  // Set the expire time
  exp.setTime(exp + 2592000000);
  // Set a 'time' cookie with the current timer time and expire time object.
  setCookie('time', time, exp);
};

// Asign on click event to 'getCookie' button
document.getElementById('getCookie').onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('lastTime').value = formatTime(getCookie('time'));
};

// Function that will call when document loaded.
window.onload = function () {
  // Get the time saved into the cookie and turn it to number.
  var oldTime = parseInt(getCookie('time'), 10);
  if (0 < oldTime) { // If the time saved
    time = oldTime; // Set the current time to the saved time
  } else { // If not time saved
    time = 0; // Set the current time to zero.
  }

  // Start the timer
  switcher();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cg358/)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. it works, but still i can't recover it and start counting again.. any suggestions?

Comment: @LukeSkywalker What do you mean about "recover it and start counting again"?

Comment: I want to store the current timer value in a cookie when the user closes the browser and when it opens again, the time should start counting where it stopped. got it? :)

Comment: Thank you! you're awesome!! i'll need some time to understand what you've done here, as i'm starting with javascript now. Thank you again!!

Comment: @LukeSkywalker I am going to add comment into the code to let you understand it right now.

Comment: Many thanks Fong-Wan. Seems you had a lot of work for doing this. you're amazing!

Answer (score 1):

The cookie value is saved as 'undefined' because you don't store the right value: `timer.value`

Change that to `totalTime` and it works:

```
<input type="button" value="Set a Cookie" onClick="setCookie('myCookie',totalTime, exp)">
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRfDr/)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. it works, but still i can't recover it and start counting again.. any suggestions?

Comment: I would create another variable that has the total amount of seconds, so no days or minutes, just seconds. If you set that in your cookie it will be easy to parse it back as integer and start counting again. Otherwise you need to parse your format: (int)d, (int) : (int) : (int)